# How to let getMapping show data spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vue application where I am making an axios.get request to my backend. I just want the data which is send from the backend to write to the console but it does not work. There is no value returned. I tried to do a request through postman the response is 200 but there is no json object shown. No errors are shown either I could not find any errors because of that.

Vue axios:

```
getMeetingTimes(){
      axios.get("http://localhost:8081/api/meetingTime/")
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response.headers)
      })
}
```

Spring entities:

MeetingSetting:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_times")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MeetingTime implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "meeting_name")
    private String meeting_name;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private String endTime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name" ,insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "meeting_name")
    private MeetingsSetting meetingName;
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class MeetingTimeService {

    @Autowired
    MeetingTimeRepository meetingTimeRepository;

    public List<MeetingTime> findAllMeetingTimes(){
    System.out.println("HALLOOO "+meetingTimeRepository.findAll());
        return meetingTimeRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

this is the log I am getting from intellj:

```
Hibernate: select meetingtim0_.id as id1_1_, meetingtim0_.meeting_date as meeting_2_1_, meetingtim0_.end_time as end_time3_1_, meetingtim0_.meeting_name as meeting_4_1_, meetingtim0_.start_time as start_ti5_1_ from meeting_times meetingtim0_
Hibernate: select meetingsse0_.id as id1_0_0_, meetingsse0_.meeting_name as meeting_2_0_0_, meetingsse0_.meeting_pw as meeting_3_0_0_, meetingsse0_.meeting_url as meeting_4_0_0_ from meeting_settings meetingsse0_ where meetingsse0_.meeting_name=?
Hibernate: select meetingsse0_.id as id1_0_0_, meetingsse0_.meeting_name as meeting_2_0_0_, meetingsse0_.meeting_pw as meeting_3_0_0_, meetingsse0_.meeting_url as meeting_4_0_0_ from meeting_settings meetingsse0_ where meetingsse0_.meeting_name=?
HALLOOO [com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.dates.MeetingTime@4b385665, com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.dates.MeetingTime@5afe0ab6, com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.dates.MeetingTime@7a395a1b, com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.dates.MeetingTime@22155873, com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.dates.MeetingTime@2b17a92a, com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.dates.MeetingTime@196ad44, com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.dates.MeetingTime@314fd6ef]
Hibernate: select meetingtim0_.id as id1_1_, meetingtim0_.meeting_date as meeting_2_1_, meetingtim0_.end_time as end_time3_1_, meetingtim0_.meeting_name as meeting_4_1_, meetingtim0_.start_time as start_ti5_1_ from meeting_times meetingtim0_
```

UPDATE

Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/meetingTime")
public class MeetingTimeController {

    @Autowired
    MeetingTimeService meetingTimeService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/" )
    public void getAllTimes(){
        meetingTimeService.findAllMeetingTimes();
    }



}
```

Save method for meetingSettings and meetingTime:

```
    @PostMapping("/")
    public void saveMeeting(@RequestBody MeetingsSetting meetingsSetting){
        meetingsSetting.getMeetingTime()
                .forEach(mt -> mt.setMeeting_name(meetingsSetting.getMeetingName()));
        // ...
        meetingSettingService.saveMeeting(meetingsSetting);

    }


}
```

this is inside meetingSettingCOntroller

This is the outcome:

```
{
        "id": 35,
        "date": "2021-06-21",
        "startTime": "11:01",
        "meeting_name": "Testeriuds",
        "endTime": "11:01",
        "meetingName": {
            "id": 17,
            "meetingName": "Testeriuds",
            "meetingUrl": null,
            "meetingPw": "",
            "meetingTime": [
                {
                    "id": 37,
                    "date": "2021-05-31",
                    "startTime": "15:30",
                    "meeting_name": "Testeriuds",
                    "endTime": "16:30",
```

THis error comes when I make the request from axios. But still shows data on the console:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.io.IOException.<init>(IOException.java:81) ~[na:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JacksonException.<init>(JacksonException.java:26) ~[jackson-core-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException.<init>(JsonProcessingException.java:25) ~[jackson-core-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException.<init>(JsonProcessingException.java:38) ~[jackson-core-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.<init>(JsonMappingException.java:245) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:785) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
```

Comment: You have to set up CORS policy. You may watch the error in navigator console. Here you can see how set up it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

Comment: I had cross origin enabled in my controller I will update my question. But what do you mean with navigator console?

Comment: just updated my question

Comment: If you press F12 in your navigator (if it is Chrome) and press console you will be aable to watch some errors that you cant see in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have your `@CrossOrigin` match the host requested by axios. Also make your controller endpoint *return* something, not just call the method:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081") // <-- because axios did 8081
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/meetingTime")
public class MeetingTimeController {

    @Autowired
    MeetingTimeService meetingTimeService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/" )
    public List<MeetingTime> getAllTimes(){             // removed void return type
        return meetingTimeService.findAllMeetingTimes(); // <-- added return here
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks this worked. But One question for some reason entity meetingSettings is send too. Is that because the both of them have a manyToOne relationship? I updated my code with the save method for both of them

Answer (score 0):

So the final error I had is called infinite recursion and can happen in Bidirectional Entity Relationship. One fix I had found was to put the @JsonManagedReference in the Entity which has the ManytoOne annotation in my case

MeetingSetting was looking like this:

```
@JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingName", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime = new HashSet<>();
```

And meetingTime is like this:

```
@JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name" ,insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "meeting_name")
    private MeetingsSetting meetingName;
```

Maye there is a better solution and I would be grateful if someone would tell me if my solution is correct or a bad choice.

Comment: It seem like the serialize cause the recursion issue, just added `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "meetingName")` in the above class `MeetingTime` and added `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "meetingTime")` in the above class `MeetingsSetting` to break recursive.

Comment: Hi, just curiosity which solution would be more best practice like yours or mine?